# My angular 'enter' animation is snapping at the end as the margin-bottom on the divs contents are rendered

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have an angular animation which expands the height of the page once the content is ready, then fades in the content.

```
export const CustomAnimationFadeInLoadedContent = trigger('contentLoaded', [
  transition(':enter', [
    style({ opacity: 0, height: '0px' }),
    sequence([
      animate('600ms 400ms ease-in-out', style({ height: '*' })),
      animate('400ms ease-in-out', style({ opacity: 1 }))
    ])
  ])
]);
```

The issue is that the 'div' that this animation is called on contains other elements that may have a 'margin-bottom' applied to them.

It looks like this margin is not accounted for until the animation completes, then the page snaps higher by the px value of all the margins.

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong here, or if there is a way to account for the margins of the children in the heigh: '*' value?

I Have tried using key-frames and also heigh auto, but neither make any difference.

My only solution so far is to insert `animate('10ms ease-in-out', style({ height: 'auto' })),` in to the animation. It kind of triggers so quickly its not really noticeable, but i appreciate this is a terrible solution.